# HTTP GET request made with jquery ajax to Open Weather Map API giving 404 despite working in address bar

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

I'm trying to write a program that:

1) Requests weather data from Open Weather Map (http://openweathermap.org/api) given the user's latitude and longitude.

2) Writes the requested JSON resource's weather description attribute to a text node on the page.

The HTTP GET request I pass to the $.getJSON() method seems to meet the Open Weather Map API's specifications and works when I send it via my browser's address bar, but it returns a 404 when I run it from the codepen.io file holding the full program. Does this have something to do with how codepen is interacting with OWM? Does OWM not respond to cross-origin requests from codepen or do I need to do something extra so it does? I've tried using a CORS proxy service to no avail, and have seen other pens make this API request successfully and am at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong. Any advice is extremely appreciated. Below is the js file in question. As a side note, I've read that it's important to keep API keys secret so I've removed mine, but I'd like people trying to help me to be able to run my codepen if they choose. Is there some way I can include the API key without actually showing it?

```
/* This program uses Open Weather Map's API to get the description of the weather given the user's location */

$(function() {
  // strings to be used to construct request
  var apiKey = "***insert API key***";
  var baseURL = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";
  // stores latitude and longitude attributes of requested JSON resource
  var latitude, longitude;

  function getLocation() {
    /* gets user's location */
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail);
    }
  }

  function success(position) {
    /* if browser returns location, displays weather for that location */
    latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    display(constructRequest(latitude, longitude));
  }

  function fail() {
    /* runs if user's location is not returned */
    console.log('fail');
  }

  function constructRequest(lat, long) {
    /* constructs and returns http request based on user's latitude and longitude */
    return baseURL + "?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + long + "&APPID=" + apiKey;
  }

  function display(req) {
    /* displays the weather description given by the requested JSON object */
    $.getJSON(req,
      function(data) {
        $('#display').text(data.weather[0].description);
      }
    );
  }

  getLocation();
});
```

Comment: The base URL does not seem to have the protocol (http) - the browser's address bar may insert it for you automatically.  Can you try the base URL with the protocol in place?

Comment: HA! You found it. This is my first time playing with API's so of course I thought there must have been something spooky going on behind the scenes. Thanks for your help. I think I might take this question down since its just a typo and probably won't be of much use to others.

Comment: Feel free to remove it... glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base URL does not seem to have the protocol (http)

Please add the necessary protocol for your URL, as in:

`var baseURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";`